# Currency Detection Defaults to the USD with the $ symbol

Tags: import.io

I can select a currency with a currency column but the value is always in USD, is it possible to change the currency iso code?

E.g. $39.99 this is in Canadian dollars but always appears 39.99 USD.

I see you can use text but then i am stuck with the $ symbol.

Right now i have had to use a regular expression to drop the $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that the price you see is through your own IP address, but when you run your API you are calling the API on our American servers for you. The website registers our servers' US IP address and display their price in US dollars instead. Unfortunately, at this time, you cannot change the currency.

If you are using a Crawler, in the Advanced Options (by toggling the Simple button to Advanced), choose to crawl Locally instead, this will use your own IP address, and should therefore display the price in your desired currency.

Thanks,
Meg